# AJAX ModalDialogBox IE 7 and above not spporting

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-7

```
 I am trying to achive a ause functionality in javascript.
```

I am making an asynchronous AJAX call and trying to achive synhronous functionality of AJAX. I want to pause the javascript until i receive the AJAX response for the asyn call of AJAX. Due to some reason i am not using the AJAX synchronous call which will solve my problem.

Once i make a call i use the following two functions to pause the JS

```
function pause2(numberMillis) {
            var dialogScript = "window.setTimeout(" +
                               " function () { document.write(' '); window.close(); }, "
                               + numberMillis + ");";
            var result = window.showModalDialog('javascript.document.writeln(' +
                        '"<script>' + dialogScript + '<' + '/script>")');
 }



function pause3()
{

do
{
 if(lmsCommitTimeOut<9000){
 lmsCommitTimeOut=lmsCommitTimeOut+1000;    
 pause2(1000);
 }
 else
 {
   //alert("TimeOut"); 
   lmsCommitStatus="false"; 
   return;
 }

}while(readStateAchived=="false")

}
```

I call the pause3(); function which internally calls the pause2(1000) for every 1sec until i get the ajax response back, which i check with the help of a js variable "readStateAchived".

This is working well in IE6, but in IE7 it is poping up the modal window and not getting closed, I have to close it manually.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: What you should do is, put the rest of the script in the callback function of your ajax call. Voila, you have your ajax call synchronized.

Comment: Sorry...your answar is not clear